# How to edit special character in Linux files using with SED?

Tags: awk, sed

**File name: File.txt**
Content:

```
Vignesh Mani Bani Ravi
```

Result should come with,

```
"Vignesh", "Mani", "Bani", "Ravi"
```

Can anyone help me how can I get the expected result?

I have tried this command.

```
 sed -e 's/^ /" ",/g' File.txt
```

It's not working. Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with awk:

```
awk -v OFS=", " -v q='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=q $i q}7' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/ /", "/g; s/^\|$/"/g' file
"Vignesh", "Mani", "Bani", "Ravi"
```

Comment: you forgot  `-i`

Comment: No I didn't. Adding `-i` would make the script non-portable and able to corrupt the input file if the OP isn't careful, and there's no indication in  the question that the OP wants to change the input file rather than just outputting the modified text.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks a lot. it really awesome and satisfied my expected result.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you here.

```
awk -v s1='"' -v s2=',' '{gsub(/ /,s1 s2 OFS s1);gsub(/^|$/,s1)} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

```
awk -v s1='"' 'BEGIN{OFS=s1", "s1} {gsub(/^|$/,s1);$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+/"&"/g;s/\s\+/, /g' file
```

Surround non-white space by double quotes. Replace each set of white space by a comma followed by a space.